# Having trouble converting encodings to tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tokenized my text data and I have onehot encoded labels, I am trying to convert my data into tensors and I get `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'`.

```
#convert encodings to tensors
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(train_encodings),
    list(y_train.values)))

val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(val_encodings),
    list(y_val.values)))
```